# ¿Cómo arreglar este error "Swift_TransportException Cannot send message without a sender address http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/resend" en Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel-6

Estoy usando laravel 6 con login, quiero que se verifique el email que se ingreso, pero a la hora de enviar el correo me sale: 
`Swift_TransportException
Cannot send message without a sender address 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/resend` 
En un video tutorial que segui y solo modifico el `.env`

[Link del video tutorial que seguí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=fky1mw2HnvM)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=d488746bb0985a
MAIL_PASSWORD=9a886c6a282107
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

el error me sale cuando le pongo `click here to request another`

[image: botón para enviar]

[image: error]

Comment: Te falta un correo del que envía en **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null**. No debe ser null

Comment: ¿Y cual es el que se pone? dame un ejemplo por favor @Bicho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema es que tienes que poner una dirección de correo del emisor, es decir, del que teóricamente envía el correo.

Por eso te pone en la descripción del error: **Cannot send message without a sender address**

Para ello deberías poner una dirección de correo (*no hace falta que sea real, pero debe ser de tu dominio del servidor*) en el SENDER de tu fichero **.env**

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=norequest@tudominio
```

Comment: Anotación extra, como veo que estas usando un servicio de correo externo (mailtrap.io), tu dirección podria ser norequest@mailtrap.io

Comment: En caso de querer usar Gmail, ¿Cómo se tiene que configurar el **.env**?

Comment: intentaré responder aquí aunque está limitado. Pongo entre paréntesis cada línea. (MAIL_DRIVER=smtp) (MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com) (MAIL_PORT=465) (MAIL_USERNAME=TU_GMAIL_EMAIL) (MAIL_PASSWORD=TU_GMAIL_PASSWORD) (MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl)

Comment: Y no olvides activar la opción de tu cuenta gmail: SECURiTY -> "Less secure app access" -> ON  (suele estar off)

Comment: Dice que si activo eso ya no estaría seguro mi correo, es recomendable hacerlo en una cuenta que no sea personal o sin ningún problema se puede usar?

Comment: No es recomendable. Tu servicio web puede ser utilizado de forma incorrecta para hacer spam, por ejemplo. En tal caso tu cuenta será bloqueada.